# Speed Improvements to Leave One Group Out in Large Datasets

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, regression, cross-validation

I am performing classification by [LogisticRegression](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html) over a large dataset (1.5 million observations) using [LeaveOneGroupOut](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.LeaveOneGroupOut.html) cross-validation. I am using `scikit-learn` for implementation. My code takes around 2 days to run and I would appreciate your inputs on how to make it faster. A snippet of my code is shown below:

```
grp = data['id_x'].values
logo = LeaveOneGroupOut()
LogReg = LogisticRegression()
params_grid = {'C': [0.78287388,  1.19946909,  1.0565957 ,  0.69874106, 0.88427995, 1.33028731,  0.51466415,  0.91421747,  1.25318725,  0.82665192, 1, 10],
'penalty': ['l1', 'l2']  }

random_search = RandomizedSearchCV(LogReg, param_distributions = params_grid, n_iter = 3, cv = logo, scoring = 'accuracy')
random_search.fit(X, y, grp)

print random_search.best_params_
print random_search.best_score_
```

Comment: What's `id_x`? Is it just an index over samples in X. If yes, then does that mean that you are trying to cross-validate leaving only a single sample at a time? Anyways, without your data and complete code, we are of not much help.

Comment: This question makes a lot of assumptions. I don't know what `id_x` is (and its corresponding value), what `LeaveOneGroupOut` function does, etc. For all I know, you have an endless loop in one of those functions.

Comment: @VivekKumar grp = data['id_x'].values takes the values of groups. for example id =1 ,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,.... this is my complete code. I am trying to do Logistic with  one group out (cross validation with) the code works well and I will have result after 2 days. I was wondering if there is a better solution to handle a large dataset. I also applied LogisticRegressionCV and it did not help so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am going to make the following assumptions:
1- you are using scikit-learn.
2- you need your code to be faster.

To get your final results faster, you can train multiple models at once by running them in parallel. To do so, you need to modify the variable `n_jobs` in scikit-learn. Possible options for `n_jobs` can be `#of_CPU_cores` or `#of_CPU_cores-1` if you are not running anything else on your computer while training the model.

**Examples:**

*RandomizedSearchCV* in parallel:

```
random_search = RandomizedSearchCV(LogReg, n_jobs=3, param_distributions = params_grid, n_iter = 3, cv = logo, scoring = 'accuracy')
```

*LogisticRegression* in parallel:

```
LogisticRegression(n_jobs=3)
```

I recommend parallelizing only *RandomizedSearchCV*.

It might be helpful to also look at the original scikit-learn documentations:

- [sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html)
- [sklearn.model_selection.RandomizedSearchCV](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.RandomizedSearchCV.html)

Comment: I added n_jobs = 3 and n_iter = 1. It became relatively better but still not improves so much.

Comment: can you post your computer specs? (fyi, I don't think n_iter=1 would produce any useful result)

Comment: I think it should help some how, as the number of parameters settings that are tried out (sklearn definition) will be decreased in comparison with n_iter = 3. setting n_jobs =3 and n_iter =1 helps for LogisticRegression. Right now I am performing SVM which is so slow even though with n_job =3 and _iter=1

Comment: If you have 1.5M datapoints, you should probably use neural networks instead. Other models don't scale well with a large number of observations. Also, you don't need to do grid search now (also known as RandomizedSearchCV) if you are unsure which algorithm you are going to use to process your data. I suggest first deciding on your method (SVM, Logistic Regression, NN, etc.) based on the nature of the data and previous papers in the field; and then perform optimization for best results possible.
I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, it is my supervisor advise to do Logistic Regression, Decision Tree ,Random Forest and SVM. we will probably  try NN very soon.